# Method to add dynamic content to ADFS log in / sign in page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adfs

We've had a request from our marketing department for the ability to easily add and update on a semi-frequent basis, short messages or announcements on the ADFS sign-in page. Has anyone tried this? Recommend or not?

One method could be to use onload.js and CSS to retrieve an RSS feed from an external WordPress site and display the content of a particular post somewhere on the sign in page. Thoughts?

Comment: The only way to customise ADFS is via onload.js. Be mindful of security.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought. We may have to consider a different approach.